# Change a value in a Select depending on the selected value in another Select

Tags: reactjs, select

My application has two fields for selecting options, and I would like to set up a dependency between these fields.

In one field the user can select the payment system ('visa' or 'master'), and depending on this choice, different values (1000$,3000$,5000$ or 2000$,4000$,8000$) should appear in the other field.

Take a look at the file below

```
export const pay: Pay[] = [
  {
    name: 'visa',
    bitrates: [
      { name: '1000$', value: 1000 },
      { name: '3000$', value: 3000 },
      { name: '5000$', value: 5000 },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'master',
    bitrates: [
      { name: '2000$', value: 2000 },
      { name: '4000$', value: 4000 },
      { name: '8000$', value: 8000 },
    ],
  },
];
```

Next, I have three components: one common to two selects, and 2 with selects.
For the Select field I use the Radix library https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/select. But regardless of the library, I would like to understand the principle of how to change the values in the PriceSelect component depending on the values in the PaySistemSelect component
Take a look below

CommonOptions.tsx

```
export function CommonOptions() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PaySistemSelect />
      <PriceSelect />
    </div>
  );
}
```

PaySistemSelect.tsx

```
export function PaySistemSelect() {
  return (
    <Select.Root>
      <Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Value placeholder="Select pay sistem" />
      </Select.Trigger>
      <Select.Content>
        <Select.Viewport>
          <Select.Item key="" value="" />
          {/* {listWithPaySistem.map((res) => ( */}
          <Select.Item
            // key={res.id}
            value="Something"
          >
            {/* <Select.ItemText>{res.name}</Select.ItemText> */}
          </Select.Item>
          {/* ))} */}
        </Select.Viewport>
      </Select.Content>
    </Select.Root>
  );
}
```

PriceSelect.tsx

```
export function PriceSelect() {
  return (
    <Select.Root>
      <Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Value placeholder="Select price" />
      </Select.Trigger>
      <Select.Content>
        <Select.Viewport>
          <Select.Item key="" value="" />
          {/* {listWithPrice.map((res) => ( */}
          <Select.Item
            // key={res.id}
            value="Something"
          >
            {/* <Select.ItemText>{res.name}</Select.ItemText> */}
          </Select.Item>
          {/* ))} */}
        </Select.Viewport>
      </Select.Content>
    </Select.Root>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should store the payment system select value in the parent component and pass the value and selection callback function to the first select component. The second select component will have only the selected payment system property passed from the parent, so you can set/filter select options depending on that value. That's a common React approach of sharing state between components, check docs for more details  https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components Other option is to use some state management library to avoid props drilling if you have more complex components hierarchy.

Comment: @ArtyomGanev Thanks for the advice. I tried to do it in a similar way: but either I’m not passing the parameters correctly from the parent component to the child component, or I’m doing something wrong with the Radix library, but I can’t get the two fields to work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [Artyom Ganev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6880595/artyom-ganev)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926868/change-a-value-in-a-select-depending-on-the-selected-value-in-another-select#comment137397965_77926868), you would need to use React's state and props to pass the selected payment system value from the `CommonOptions` parent component to both `PaySistemSelect` and `PriceSelect` components. It would allow `PriceSelect` to dynamically update its options based on the selected payment system in `PaySistemSelect`.

First, maintain the state for the selected payment system in the `CommonOptions` component. That state will be updated whenever a new payment system is selected and passed down to both `PaySistemSelect` and `PriceSelect`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { PaySistemSelect } from './PaySistemSelect';
import { PriceSelect } from './PriceSelect';
import { pay } from './payData'; // Assuming payData is the file with your `pay` array

export function CommonOptions() {
  const [selectedPaySystem, setSelectedPaySystem] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <PaySistemSelect
        setSelectedPaySystem={setSelectedPaySystem}
      />
      <PriceSelect
        selectedPaySystem={selectedPaySystem}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Modify `PaySistemSelect` to accept a `setSelectedPaySystem` function via props. Use this function to update the parent's state when a payment system is selected. It uses [Radix](https://www.radix-ui.com/), here the [`Select` component](https://www.radix-ui.com/themes/docs/components/select) to create the dropdown menus for selecting a payment system and the corresponding price options.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Select from '@radix-ui/react-select';

export function PaySistemSelect({ setSelectedPaySystem }) {
  return (
    <Select.Root onValueChange={setSelectedPaySystem}>
      <Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Value placeholder="Select pay system" />
      </Select.Trigger>
      <Select.Content>
        <Select.Viewport>
          <Select.Item key="visa" value="visa">
            <Select.ItemText>Visa</Select.ItemText>
          </Select.Item>
          <Select.Item key="master" value="master">
            <Select.ItemText>Master</Select.ItemText>
          </Select.Item>
        </Select.Viewport>
      </Select.Content>
    </Select.Root>
  );
}
```

From there, `PriceSelect` needs to filter the available options based on the selected payment system. It will receive the `selectedPaySystem` as a prop:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Select from '@radix-ui/react-select';
import { pay } from './payData'; // Assuming this is your data file

export function PriceSelect({ selectedPaySystem }) {
  const options = pay.find(p => p.name === selectedPaySystem)?.bitrates || [];

  return (
    <Select.Root>
      <Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Value placeholder="Select price" />
      </Select.Trigger>
      <Select.Content>
        <Select.Viewport>
          {options.map((option) => (
            <Select.Item key={option.value} value={option.name}>
              <Select.ItemText>{option.name}</Select.ItemText>
            </Select.Item>
          ))}
        </Select.Viewport>
      </Select.Content>
    </Select.Root>
  );
}
```

That should allow you to share state between sibling components by lifting the state up to their common parent and passing it down as props.

---

> at the moment, when opening a page with the `PaySistemSelect` and `PaySistemSelect` fields, these fields are empty (even if something was selected earlier). How can I set them to default values?
> I see that `Select.Root` has `defaultValue` and `value` in its parameters. How can they be applied and what should be written there?

You should be able to use the `defaultValue` property of `Select.Root` in Radix UI.
However, if you want to restore selections based on user actions or saved preferences beyond the initial load, you might transition to using `value` and manage the state changes through user interactions or effects.

`value` makes the component controlled by React, meaning you manage its state externally via props. Use this if you need to programmatically update the selected value after the initial render.

---

> This solution (`defaultValue`) only works for the initial case with "`visa`". If I select "`master`" then the `PriceSelect` field becomes empty.

If the `PriceSelect` field becomes empty upon selecting "`master`", it could be due to the `PriceSelect` component not having a mechanism to update its default value based on the newly selected payment system after the initial render. When you switch from "`visa`" to "`master`", the `PriceSelect` needs to dynamically adjust its options and potentially set a new default value corresponding to the "`master`" payment system.

Try and use React's effect hook ([`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)) to listen for changes in the `selectedPaySystem` prop. That way, you can set a local state within `PriceSelect` that determines which value is selected. That approach transitions the component to be controlled by React, meaning you will use the `value` prop instead of `defaultValue` to explicitly control the selected option.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as Select from '@radix-ui/react-select';
import { pay } from './payData'; // Assuming this is your data file

export function PriceSelect({ selectedPaySystem }) {
  const options = pay.find(p => p.name === selectedPaySystem)?.bitrates || [];
  const [selectedPrice, setSelectedPrice] = useState(options.length > 0 ? options[0].name : '');

  // Update the selected price when the selected payment system changes
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedPrice(options.length > 0 ? options[0].name : '');
  }, [selectedPaySystem, options]);

  return (
    <Select.Root value={selectedPrice} onValueChange={setSelectedPrice}>
      <Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Value placeholder="Select price" />
      </Select.Trigger>
      <Select.Content>
        <Select.Viewport>
          {options.map((option) => (
            <Select.Item key={option.value} value={option.name}>
              <Select.ItemText>{option.name}</Select.ItemText>
            </Select.Item>
          ))}
        </Select.Viewport>
      </Select.Content>
    </Select.Root>
  );
}
```

By using the `value` prop on `Select.Root` and managing the selected value through state (`selectedPrice`), `PriceSelect` becomes a controlled component. That means its current value is always driven by React state, allowing for dynamic updates based on user interactions or external changes (like switching the payment system).

Comment: Thank you very much for paying attention to my question. I'll definitely appreciate it. There is just one clarifying point, please tell me: at the moment, when opening a page with the PaySistemSelect and PaySistemSelect fields, these fields are empty (even if something was selected earlier). How can I set them to default values? I see that Select.Root has defaultValue and value in its parameters. How can they be applied and what should be written there?

Comment: Thank you. But this solution only works for the initial case with "visa". If I select "master" then the PriceSelect field becomes empty

Comment: @Paul Good point. I have edited the answer to address that.

Comment: Its really strong and pretty solution, thank you. You are great programmer!

Comment: For now, the system prohibits awarding you a bounty. I'll do it as soon as possible

Comment: @Paul It not urgent ;) Re-Reading this answer, what part could I delete? After your tests, what was not needed in that answer?

Comment: I think you can leave only the last PriceSelect, PaySistemSelect with defaultValue, and the original CommonOptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256778/discussion-between-vonc-and-paul).